# iDevice slows render when there's no interaction

Tags: c#, ios, opengl-es

I'm making an application in C# Xamarin that uses a `iPhoneOSGameView` for rendering some video stream I receive from the network. The problem is that after around 10 seconds without any user interaction with the screen, the frame rate drops significantly. It seems that the iDevice is going into some sort of power saving mode. When I interact with the screen (e.g. I pull down the top bar menu (iOS menu)), the frame rate goes back up, just like the iDevice realized I was actually using the application now.

Is there a setting/value I have to set in my application to prevent this type of CPU/GPU low consumption mode?

Note: it seems that the GPU is going in this mode, since the time elapsed between updates and between renders stays the same (~16.6 ms).