# iOS reducing cpu consumption when no UI interaction

Tags: c#, ios, uikit

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036817/idevice-slows-render-when-theres-no-interaction) question yesterday about an OpenGL/GPU problem with my app. After hours of profiling and console outputs, I figured that CPU consumption is greatly reduced when there's no interaction for about 10 seconds. When there's a popup, a title bar update or something that makes iOS think the cpu should go back up, the application starts running like it should... for 10 seconds again! There's got to be a setting somewhere to prevent iOS from thinking my app is not active. Or maybe a method call I could add after my render loop to notify iOS I'm still active?

I tried to call `SetNeedsDisplay` after the render method, without any success. I was looking for a setting in the info.plist but also couldn't find anything interesting there.

Note: I profiled the application using Instruments and found out that the network card is lowering in load when the said "lag" happens. Hopefully this can help.

Comment: Request for additional information: Which iOS build? Which device?Are you running on battery or on AC power? What rendering method do you use? (EAGLView?)

Comment: I build for iOS 8.4 ans run all my tests on many different devices. I usually am plugged in the computer, but the issue is there while unplugged too. I use an EAGLView.